# How to reference to another page id using ahref link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have a page where i used to referene to another page div id and trigger click event for edit particular div form fields.

Profile page

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('settings_pro/edit'); ?>" name="pull-right" class="edits editabil" id="showEdit">EDIT PROFILE</a>
```

Settings page

```
<div id="edit"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(settings_pro/edit){
        $("#edit").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

I am using codeigniter it redirect to error page. how to achieve it in codeigniter

Comment: what do you want with 'settings_pro/edit'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a link with hash tag like this `<?php echo base_url('settings_pro#edit'); ?>`

In jquery get the hash tag value return by url and perform the operation whatever you needs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#')+1); // get the hash tag value
  if(hash == "edit"){
    //do whatever you needs
    $("#edit").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

Comment: `var url  = window.location.href;`